# Custom sorting (non-alphabetical)

Tags: r, sorting, categories

I have a categorical data set that looks similar to:

```
A < -data.frame(animal = c("cat","cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","elephant","elephant","elephant"),
                color = c(rep(c("blue","red","green"), 3)))

    animal color
1      cat  blue
2      cat   red
3      cat green
4      dog  blue
5      dog   red
6      dog green
7 elephant  blue
8 elephant   red
9 elephant green
```

I want to order it so that 'animal' is sorted as `dog < elephant < cat`, and then the color is sorted `green < blue < red`.  So in the end it would look like

```
#     animal color
# 6      dog green
# 4      dog  blue
# 5      dog   red
# 9 elephant green
# 7 elephant  blue
# 8 elephant   red
# 3      cat green
# 1      cat  blue
# 2      cat   red
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The levels should be specified explicitly:

```
A$animal <- factor(A$animal, levels = c("dog", "elephant","cat"))
A$color <- factor(A$color, levels = c("green", "blue", "red"))
```

Then you order by the 2 columns simultaneously:

```
A[order(A$animal,A$color),]

# animal color
# 6      dog green
# 4      dog  blue
# 5      dog   red
# 9 elephant green
# 7 elephant  blue
# 8 elephant   red
# 3      cat green
# 1      cat  blue
# 2      cat   red
```

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `match` - you do not alter column class neither do a `factor` transformation.

```
animalOrder = c("dog", "elephant","cat")
colorOrder  = c("green", "blue", "red")
A[ order(match(A$animal, animalOrder), match(A$color, colorOrder)), ]

animal color
6      dog green
4      dog  blue
5      dog   red
9 elephant green
7 elephant  blue
8 elephant   red
3      cat green
1      cat  blue
2      cat   red
```

Answer (score 4):

One other thing worth noting - you don't have to convert the class to do this. You can simply order by the factor of the variable. Thus preserving as eg character class within the existing data structure, if that is desired.

so eg, using the example above:

```
A[order(factor(A$animal, levels = c("dog", "elephant","cat")) ,factor(A$color, levels = c("green", "blue", "red"))),]
```

Depends on whether conservation of class is important. This would be a much more typical use case for me personally. HTH

Answer (score 0):

In a vein similar to how [agstudy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1838509/agstudy) did it, I'd present the 'tidyverse' way of presenting the ordering:

```
A$animal <- factor(A$animal, levels = c("dog", "elephant","cat"))
A$color <- factor(A$color, levels = c("green", "blue", "red"))
```

Then we load `dplyr` or the whole `tidyverse` and can do

```
arrange(A, animal, color)
```

or simply

```
A %>% arrange(animal, color)
```

where `%>%` is the 'pipe' operator in r, and can be accessed by using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `m`