# Reordering rows in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, rows

I have a very simple problem. Here is my data frame

```
     genotype
TRS2       WT
TRS4       WT
TRS5       WT
TRS6       WT
TRS1       KO
TRS3       KO
```

I need to have KO first then WT

```
     genotype
TRS1       KO
TRS3       KO
TRS2       WT
TRS4       WT
TRS5       WT
TRS6       WT
```

How do you do this? I prefer it be done setting the order manually (KO then WT) instead of something like alphabetical order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sorting (non-alphabetical)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995285/custom-sorting-non-alphabetical)

Comment: Unfortunately that just doesn't work (and I don't know why). This code:

`sampleTable$genotype <- factor(sampleTable$genotype, levels = c("KO", "WT"))`

produces the same output as before.

Comment: You still have to sort it after that.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `arrange` as with `arrange` the column is sorted in alphabetical order.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    arrange(genotype)
```

Output:

```
  X     genotype
  <chr> <chr>   
1 TRS1  KO      
2 TRS3  KO      
3 TRS2  WT      
4 TRS4  WT      
5 TRS5  WT      
6 TRS6  WT
```

**OR**

```
df %>% 
    mutate(sorter = ifelse(genotype=="KO", 1,2)) %>% 
    arrange(sorter) %>% 
    select(-sorter)
```

Output:

```
  X     genotype
  <chr> <chr>   
1 TRS1  KO      
2 TRS3  KO      
3 TRS2  WT      
4 TRS4  WT      
5 TRS5  WT      
6 TRS6  WT
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom order and use `dplyr`

```
df$genotypeOrder  = factor(df$genotype, levels = c("KO", "WT"))
df %>% arrange(genotypeOrder)
```