# Ordering a dataframe based on a custom vector

Tags: r, dataframe

Let say I have below `dataframe` in `R`

```
dat = data.frame('col1' = letters[1:10], 'col2' = c('A', 'X', 'D', 'Y', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'X', 'D', 'A'))
```

I want to first order this dataframe w.r.t the `col2` based on a defined vector `c('D', 'Y', 'X', 'A')` and then again order based on `col1` but in descending order.

Is there any way to achieve this in `R`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom sorting (non-alphabetical)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995285/custom-sorting-non-alphabetical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `factor` to define the ordering and use `desc` to invert it:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame('col1' = letters[1:10], 'col2' = c('A', 'X', 'D', 'Y', 'A', 'D', 'Y', 'X', 'D', 'A'))

dat <-
  dat %>%
  mutate(
    col2 = col2 %>% factor(levels = c('D', 'Y', 'X', 'A'))
  )

dat %>% arrange(col2)
#>    col1 col2
#> 1     c    D
#> 2     f    D
#> 3     i    D
#> 4     d    Y
#> 5     g    Y
#> 6     b    X
#> 7     h    X
#> 8     a    A
#> 9     e    A
#> 10    j    A
dat %>% arrange(desc(col1))
#>    col1 col2
#> 1     j    A
#> 2     i    D
#> 3     h    X
#> 4     g    Y
#> 5     f    D
#> 6     e    A
#> 7     d    Y
#> 8     c    D
#> 9     b    X
#> 10    a    A
```

Comment: Why is it `arrange(col2)` and then `arrange(desc(col1))` instead of `arrange(col2, desc(col1))`? I almost never see people doing the former.

Comment: `arrange(col2, desc(col1))` arranges primarily by `col2`. Only if there are rows with the same value of `col2`, they are reordered in this row group using `col1`.

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between them. I just cannot imagine a senario that I need to arrange two columns separately instead of joiltly.

Comment: Depends on the question. You might want to do `arrange(continent, country)` in one question and `arrange(cost)` or `arrange(desc(profit))` in others

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `left_join`:

```
library(dplyr)

vector <- c('D', 'Y', 'X', 'A') 

left_join(data.frame(col2 = vector),    # Reorder data frame
                       dat,
                       by = "col2") %>% 
  arrange(desc(col1))
```

```
   col2 col1
1     A    j
2     D    i
3     X    h
4     Y    g
5     D    f
6     A    e
7     Y    d
8     D    c
9     X    b
10    A    a
```